# Что не так с моим кодом? MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При нажатию на кнопки в ItemsControl'е слева должно генерироваться поле в соответствии с данными в левом поле размерами,но поле не генерируются
Вот весь код:
[MenuVM](http://pastebin.ru/l8xh38Wy)

[VM and GameInfo](http://pastebin.ru/FAHdxolG)

[CellVM](http://pastebin.ru/waRVN4ty)

[XAML](http://pastebin.ru/RwNqOG86)

[MenuBoardVM](http://pastebin.ru/v8V6y87X)

Comment: Ну, эээ, если ваш код не влазит в вопрос, это хороший признак того, что его для вопроса слишком много. Если поле в `ItemsControl`'е не генерируется, возможно, либо проблема с привязкой `ItemsSource` (это можно увидеть в окошке Output), либо в привязанный параметр не попадает новый список (это можно выяснить в отладчике).

Comment: @VladD оно генерируются,но только при запуске программы,размер поля зависит от одного параметра,который меняется при нажатии кнопки в левом ItemsControl'е,но вот при нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: Идёмте лучше обсудим в чат по C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После дискуссии в чате обнаружилось, что проблема в `MenuBoardVM`. Свойствf `MenuHeight`, `Width` и `Height`, как оказалось, отвечали за одно и то же: за размер поля. Проблема решилась удалением свойств `Width` и `Height`, переименованием `MenuHeight` в `FieldSize` и переписыванием сеттера `FieldSize` в

```
set { if (Set(ref fieldSize, value)) { GenerateCells(); } }
```